# How to parse JWT token in unit tests SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices

I have a microservice setup with Spring boot and OAuth 2 with JWT.
I have additional fields in my JWT token.

Most of my services call a static method that has a thread local of the additional fields in the token.
How can I write unit tests for such services?
Even if I tried to inject a mock user it doesn't work and I couldn't find a way of sending the JWT because I am no testing the controllers.

Code:

[SecurityUtils static Calss (also check the package for other relevant JWT handler)](https://github.com/MichaelAbouKhalil/TrackMe/blob/master/common-utils/src/main/java/com/trackme/common/security/SecurityUtils.java) .

[Example on a method that will call the static class (Line 79)](https://github.com/MichaelAbouKhalil/TrackMe/blob/master/user-service/src/main/java/com/trackme/userservice/service/ProfileService.java).

Method:

```
public CommonResponse saveUpdateProfile(ProfileRequest request) {

    String authUsername = SecurityUtils.getUsername();

    Optional<ProfileEntity> optionalProfile = findProfileByUsername(authUsername);

    ProfileEntity profile;
    if (optionalProfile.isPresent()) {
        profile = optionalProfile.get();
    } else {
        profile = ProfileEntity.builder()
                .username(authUsername)
                .build();
    }

    profile.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
    profile.setLastName(request.getLastName());

    ProfileEntity savedProfile = profileRepository.save(profile);

    if (savedProfile == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save user in database");
    }

    return CommonResponse.ok(savedProfile);
}
```

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Can you show some rlevant code? How are you trying to inject the user. How that static method looks like. How is it called from a service. How a test looks like. This will help to resolve your problem. Now it's a bit too vague.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski yes sorry, I added github reference, I didn't add the tests but you can find them in github, the tests implements my previous way of doing it which is retrieving from SecurityContext, I couldn't yet find a way to do from JWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so that's a common problem when using static methods. You can't easily override them, e.g. in tests. I think what I would do is to turn your `SecurityUtils` class into a service and make it implement an interface. Then inject this interface into any other service that needs to use it, instead of calling static methods. Then you can easily provide another implementation to your tests.

So you would have something like that:

```
interface SecurityUtils {
    String getUsername();
    ...
}

@Service
class MySecurityUtils immplements SecurityUtils {
    private JwtToken getJwtToken() {
        return MySecurityContextHolder.getContext().getJwtToken();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return getJwtToken().getUsername();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in the unit test you can just inject a mock implementation of `SecurityUtils` to any class you're testing.

Comment: I applied a fix to my tests using mock-inline to mock static methods. Do you think using your solution is better? I've read that people don't really like moccking static methods, so I'm not sure.

Comment: This solution is definitely cleaner. I think you should mock static methods only if you have no other choice (e.g. you use a method from a 3rd party library). You are in control of this code, so in my opinion it's better to go with interfaces and injecting the right implementation.

Comment: okay I got it thank you for the explanation. I'll do as u said